# Fancyhdr: How to change from lower case Roman numbers to upper case Roman number the pagenumbering of the preamble?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using the book class and I need to change the numbering of the first pages from lower case Roman numbers to upper case Roman numbers. I am using something like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Title of the book}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

I believe I should use something like

```
\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}{Roman}
```

However, I am not able to access the page numbering of the preamble (I mean the first pages that include basically the table of contents.

Edit: [Minimal working example]

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,portrait,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{To do}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

%\doublespace
\title{This book}
\author{Myself} \maketitle

\pagebreak

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}\label{capitulo_introducao}
%
%
This is my introduction

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, `\pagenumbering{Roman}` is sufficient, but this has nothing to do with `fancyhdr` ;-) The `\renewcommand` is wrong!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you! However, when I use \pagenumbering{Roman} nothing happens. It was my first attempt.

Comment: Please show us a MWE in order to give us some insight.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry, what do you mean about MWE?

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you again. I have just provided the MWE

Comment: I spotted the 'error': `\mainmatter` switches back to arabic page numbering: You can easily drop both `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands, they are quite useless, in my point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\frontmatter` switches to `roman` (lower case) numbers, and `\mainmatters` switches back to arabic numbers, so if this should be prevented, it means either dropping `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` or patch this behaviour out of those macros using `xpatchcmd` from *egreg's* `xpatch` package.

*I was a little bit lazy about the success/failure test of the command `\xpatchcmd` ;-)*

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,portrait,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}%

\xpatchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\mainmatter}{\pagenumbering{arabic}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{To do}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\makeindex


\begin{document}

%\doublespace
\title{This book}
\author{Myself} \maketitle

\pagebreak

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}\label{capitulo_introducao}
%
%
This is my introduction

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you again! However, after the first page, the page number arises in two places in the botton and in the right position of the head. I know how to remove the one in the one in the head, but I should keep this one (editorial format)!

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: Please don't edit answers -- You gave that MWE, I concentrated on the Roman page number stuff, not on bottom/header positions

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. I was trying to edit the question, since the minimal example does not consider the pages where there is the head.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: Then change your MWE, but try not to change the whole initial question ;-)

Comment: Your solution works well if I include \lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}. Maybe You want to modify your answer for future reference! Thank u (:-) Actually the problem was with my question that was too minimal!

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: Well, thanks for accepting (and upvoting), but the issue that the footer should be empty was not in your question ;-)

Comment: sure, thank you! The problem only arised when I created the minimal example.